# 'Extended' Tracking?

Tags: tracking

I seem to have 2D tracking and camera tracking in After Effects licked. Blender tracking, however - is foxing me.

I prepared my shot - putting mini beanbag tracking points down. The shot involved my walking in a 'shallow semi-circle' - I will later add a parked spacecraft to the scene. Despite the excellent contrast my ground tracking points gave, the tracking markers just would not stick to them for the duration. Naturally, I made sure all the markers remained in the shot the whole time. I had wall tracking points too.

I feel Blender as a 3D prog would have coped better with the changing perspective. I tried Location, Perspective, Affine etc - but the only thing that seemed to help was increasing the tracking marker margin area - but still my track was lost. I'm using the correct sensor size and all that stuff.

I'll appreciate any suggestions. It's going to be really frustrating having to limit camera movement because I have trouble tracking anything too adventurous.

Many thanks.

Comment: this is kind of a workaround but i use it sometimes i will track a scene in other software like after effects in your case and export a video of black with the tracked points as white dots that are easy to track in blender because blender tomato tracker isn't very reliable

Comment: Read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 If that doesn't help add more information as part of the question. 3D tracking is not that hard, but it needs to be done carefully, most problems are due to inaccurate tracking. Check that the trackers are not slipping and do whatever you can to fix that. You don't need to have all the trackers visible for the whole shot, but in a segment that is long enough for blender to solve the motion. Consider sharing the video and the blender file.

Comment: Thank you @J Block & @susu. Appreciate your feedback. I tried again and again - but was finding it just too frustrating. I looked for a way to transfer camera data from After Effects to Blender and found a script at Blender Market. It certainly had mixed reviews and there was no mention of it working in 2.91 - but it's working for me. It feels incomplete - but the tutorial guy included a workaround for its limitations. This is a great development and I'm very happy to have a found a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Please post your video track and blender file. The tracker is quite robust, so far it has not failed to solve anything I've thrown at it. However, if you found a solution post it as an answer in the answers section, so that others can learn from your experience.